# getting a multi decimal number from a string

Tags: java, numbers

For one of my projects i would like to get a version from a string which has multiple decimals, is it possible to convert it into a multi decimal point double or is it not possible. I would like to use this to see if it is more than  the previous one, which would also have multiple decimals.

What I am using at the moment is
`if (!vers.equalsIgnoreCase(plugin.getDescription().getVersion())) { // Do stuff`
But I would like to make it so I can do 
`if (vers > plugin.getDescription().getVersion()) { // do stuff`
 `vers` is equal to 1.0.1, and the plugin.getDescription().getVersion() is equal to 1.0.2

thanks!

Comment: Please add the code you already have

Comment: I don't have any yet; i don't know how to convert it, thats my question

Comment: Let's start with what you do know, can you write a hello world program, can you input a string. Can you use `indexOf` and `substring`? Can you use `Integer.parseInt`?

Comment: I don't think you understand the question; Integer.parseInt won't work because of the decimals, and indexof and substring won't do anything because it won't change it to a number variable, therefore you cannot compare whether one number is greater than the other.

Comment: Believe me, there are people who show no code and they will say things like; I only have a phone so I haven't actually written a program before. We don't know what you don't know so help us understand what is the actual problem you are having is.

Comment: I suggest you read my whole comment and if you use those things in combination it will work.

Comment: Please show atleast an example of your input....which you want to convert...

Comment: Like said in the description, I would like to have a number variable that has multiple decimals, I will post my existing code in a sec

Comment: Convert your string to a char array. check for every char in the array with a loop if it is a '.'. If its not a '.' you should have a number. Then you can parse that number into an int. So if you have a version name with 3 numbers you would have to use 3 integers or an integerarray

Comment: It sounds like you understand all the pieces of the puzzle if you know what Integer.parseInt is, you just don't know how to use them in combination... My mind reading skills are not at 110% today. ;)

Comment: Can you show us you code for decoding the versions so you can do the comparison? e.g. start with `public static int compare(String vers1, String vers2)` which return -1, 0 or 1.

Comment: The class I use doesn't implement Comparable, and if it did, I'm not sure how I could compare the multiple decimal numbers together. I could do it with a Double, only until it gets to 2 decimals in the version string

Comment: All your version are same length or not?

Comment: I didn't mention Comparable though String is Comparable, though you can use it that way as "2" > "10" see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could implement this way, if you assume all the portions are numbers.

```
public static int compareVersions(String vers1, String vers2) {
    String[] v1 = vers1.split("\\.");
    String[] v2 = vers2.split("\\.");
    for (int i = 0; i < v1.length && i < v2.length; i++) {
        int i1 = Integer.parseInt(v1[i]);
        int i2 = Integer.parseInt(v2[i]);
        int cmp = Integer.compare(i1, i2);
        if (cmp != 0)
            return cmp;
    }
    return Integer.compare(v1.length, v2.length);
}
```

and

```
System.out.println(compareVersions("1.0.1", "1.0.2"));
System.out.println(compareVersions("1.0.1", "1.0"));
System.out.println(compareVersions("1.0.2", "1.0.10"));
```

prints

```
-1
1
-1
```

A more complex version supports letters inside versions

```
public static int compareVersions(String vers1, String vers2) {
    String[] v1 = vers1.split("\\.");
    String[] v2 = vers2.split("\\.");
    for (int i = 0; i < v1.length && i < v2.length; i++) {
        String [] w1 = v1[i].split("(?<=\\D)(?=\\d)|(?<=\\d)(?=\\D)");
        String [] w2 = v2[i].split("(?<=\\D)(?=\\d)|(?<=\\d)(?=\\D)");
        for(int j=0;j<w1.length&&j<w2.length;j++) {
            try {
                int i1 = Integer.parseInt(w1[j]);
                int i2 = 0;
                try {
                    i2 = Integer.parseInt(w2[j]);
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    return -1;
                }
                int cmp = Integer.compare(i1, i2);
                if (cmp != 0)
                    return cmp;
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                try {
                    Integer.parseInt(w2[j]);
                    return +1;
                } catch (NumberFormatException e1) {
                    int cmp = w1[j].compareTo(w2[j]);
                    if (cmp != 0)
                        return cmp;
                }
            }
        }
        int cmp = Integer.compare(w1.length, w2.length);
        if (cmp != 0)
            return cmp;
    }
    return Integer.compare(v1.length, v2.length);
}
```

and

```
System.out.println(compareVersions("1.0.2", "1.0.2a"));
System.out.println(compareVersions("1.0.2b", "1.0.2a"));
System.out.println(compareVersions("1.8.0_66", "1.8.0_65"));
System.out.println(compareVersions("1.7.0_79", "1.8.0_65"));
```

prints

```
-1
1
1
-1
```

Comment: Although this is the best answer so far, how could you use it in the if statement, with if the first version is bigger than the second version.

Never mind that, got it.

Comment: @Banjo226 the same as compareTo() with greater than: `> 0`, greater than or equals to `>= 0` similar for less than.

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] numbers = version.split(".");
String[] numbers2 = version2.split(".");
int index = numbers.length-1;
while(numbers[index] != "."){
     index--;
}
String lastnumber = version.substring(index+1, numbers.length];
index = numbers2.length-1;
while(numbers2[index] != "."){
     index--;
}
String lastnumber2 = version.substring(index+1, numbers2.length];
if(lastnumber > lastnumber2){
    //later version
}else{
   //use the same thing to check the other numbers
}
```

Comment: String comparison doesn't work for numbers. i.e. "2" > "10"

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you would like to compare versions. Or to take decisions based on some string represented version. If the `plugin.getDescription().getVersion()` is a `String`, then you should be able to use a simple `String` comparison to establish the order between versions. Something like this should work:

```
String pluginVersion=plugin.getDescription().getVersion();
if (ensureValidVersion(pluginVersion) 
     && compareVersions(vers,pluginVersion)>0) {
  // do staff is vers is greater then plugin version
}
```

`ensureValidVersion` method will validate if you have a valid version number representation. And `compareVersions` will do a comparison for each version subcomponent.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a version number of the following form: x.y.z
You can use a similiar approach as suggested by Viacheslav Vedenin:

```
String versionNumber = "1.3.45";
String[] singleParts = versionNumbers.split(".");

int[] versionParts = new int[singleParts.length];
for(int i=0; i<singleParts.length; i++) {
    versionParts[i] = Integer.parseInt(singleParts[i]);
}
```

Now you have an array of the single parts of your version number. To compare it to a previous one you could do as follow:

```
public static boolean isGreater(int[] firstVersion, int[] secondVersion) {
    if(secondVersion.length > firstVersion.length) {
        return false;
    }else {
        if(firstVersion.length > secondVersion.length) {
            return true;
        }else {
            for(int k=0; k< firstVersion.length; k++) {
                int v1 = firstVersion[k];
                int v2 = secondVersion[k];

                if(v1 < v2) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare versions using the equality/inequality operators (`==`, `<`, `>`, `<=`, and `>=`), you have two options.

1. Use a language like C++ that supports operator overloading
2. Set a limit on the length for each string in `major.minor.build` and convert each version to an integer before comparing them. For example, if the limit on each of them is 3 (i.e. the longest version you can have is `abc.def.ghi`), then you can just use `build + minor * 10^3 + major * 10^6`.

Alternatively, you can just implement `Comparable<Version>` and have a nice OOP solution.

```
public class Example {
    static class Version implements Comparable<Version> {
        private int major;
        private int minor;
        private int build;

        public Version(String s) {
            final String[] split = s.split("\\.");
            major = Integer.parseInt(split[0]);
            minor = Integer.parseInt(split[1]);
            build = Integer.parseInt(split[2]);
        }

        public int getMajor() {
            return major;
        }

        public int getMinor() {
            return minor;
        }

        public int getBuild() {
            return build;
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(Version v) {
            if (getMajor() < v.getMajor()) {
                return -1;
            } else if (getMajor() > v.getMajor()) {
                return 1;
            } else {
                if (getMinor() < v.getMinor()) {
                    return -1;
                } else if (getMinor() > v.getMinor()) {
                    return 1;
                } else {
                    if (getBuild() < v.getBuild()) {
                        return -1;
                    } else if (getBuild() > v.getBuild()) {
                        return 1;
                    } else {
                        return 0;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s1 = "1.0.1";
        String s2 = "1.0.2";
        compare(s1, s2);
        compare(s1, s1);
        compare(s2, s2);
        compare(s2, s1);
    }

    private static void compare(String s1, String s2) {
        Version v1 = new Version(s1);
        Version v2 = new Version(s2);
        final int compareTo = v1.compareTo(v2);
        if (compareTo == -1) {
            System.out.println(s1 + " was released before " + s2);
        } else if (compareTo == 0) {
            System.out.println(s1 + " is the same as " + s2);
        } else {
            System.out.println(s1 + " was released after " + s2);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
1.0.1 was released before 1.0.2
1.0.1 is the same as 1.0.1
1.0.2 is the same as 1.0.2
1.0.2 was released after 1.0.1
```